# Novell JRBUtils How do I find a combined membership of multiple groups without duplicates

Tags: novell

Using GRPLIST.EXE from JRBUtils I can get a list of all members in one group or another, or even a list of members that appear in multiple groups (excluding the indivudals not in one or the other).

What I want though is a list of all members from GROUP A & B but no have any duplicate names.

We have 600+ members in one list, around 300-400 in another, however there are members in one list, not in the other and some that are in both.

Will be needing to import a list as a result into a distribution list in AD.

Answer (score 1):

I can't seem to dig out the syntax for the utility, but it sounds like the following pseudo-logic should work for you. You'll need two searches:

1. One to grab, "Members of Group A NOT IN Group B"
2. One to grab, "Members of Group B'

These two should give you two text-files that together contain the unique members of both Group A and Group B. Or if you're piping through to a utility that's populating the group it should work just fine. Create the group with the first search (dsadd, for instance), and modify it with the second (dsmod). Or, since JRBTools has AD tools now (didn't know that!) the text-files created by grplist should be comprehensible to adgrpadd

Comment: I am pretty sure that while you can specify Members of Group B with JRB, I do not think you can specify the members NOT in Group B part.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to ask there: http://forums.novell.com/novell-product-support-forums/open-enterprise-server/oes-netware/oes-nw-administration-tools/, that forum is dedicated for this kind of questions.

Also, I believe author of this tool still monitors this forum: http://forums.novell.com/novell-developer-forums/dev-netware/

Comment: John Baird is a really cool guy.  Often if you explain what you want, he will add it to the tool.